# Page in infinite loop when trying to change route

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change my route whenever I pickup a login token in user storage, so the user lands on the profile page or the login page. But for some reason, the page ends up in an infinite loop when I access `/` or `/login`. How do I fix it?

**controller.js**

```
$scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
  return viewLocation === $location.path();
};

vm.adsomaToken = localStorage.adsomaToken;
vm.adsomaUserId = localStorage.adsomaUserId;
vm.adsomaAccountType = localStorage.adsomaAccountType;
if(vm.adsomaToken && vm.adsomaUserId && vm.adsomaAccountType) {
   $window.location.href = "/";
} else {
   $window.location.href = "/login";
}

vm.logout = function() {
  localStorage.clear();
  $window.location.href = "/login";
};
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="gx-container" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <!-- Page Sidebar -->
    <div id="menu" class="side-nav gx-sidebar" ng-show="isActive('/login')">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directly with *$window.location* is not the best choice when you have to deal with dynamic routing.

I recommend using [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/).

With UI-Router you can register a function that will be triggered after certain events of a navigation.

Consider registering a function that will be executed when you are trying to *enter* into a *state* (or route).

In this example i have defined a **LoginHook** that check if every transition should be redirected to the *"/login"* or it can be allowed.

LoginHook.js

```
LoginHook.$inject = ['$transitions','$state'];
export function LoginHook ($transitions, $state) {
    //
    $transitions.onEnter({/*Matching every destination*/}, $transition => {
        //
        if($transition.to().name !== 'login') {
            // 
            if( user.allowed ) { // Replace this with your auth check 
                //
                return true; // Allowing access
            } else {
                //
                redirectToLogin(); // Redirecting to "login" 
            }
        } else {
            // Avoiding auth checking if i'm going to "login"
            return true;
        }
    })
    //
    function redirectToLogin() {
        //
        $state.go('login');
    }
}
```

**EDITED ANSWER**

As i can see in your bin you should handle the current navigation before superseeding it with another one.

Try this:

```
resolve: {
    data: function ($location, $window, $q) {
        if(!localStorage.adsomaToken && !localStorage.adsomaUserId && 
           !localStorage.adsomaAccountType) {
           //
           $q.reject('NOT ALLOWED');
           $location.path('/login');
        } else {
           $q.resolve('ALLOWED');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with $routeProvider? This is what I am doing at the moment: https://pastebin.com/05E7zPsd